# how do i get the url query parameters in google sites with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I need a way to get the url query parameters in Google Sites with Apps Script.

I'm looking for something similar to `$_GET` from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The `doGet` function has a single parameter - `e`. To access to an url parameter services `e.parameter.Param_Name`. Here are more details - [Link](http://google-data-api.blogspot.de/2011/06/get-url-parameter-from-published-google.html)